# Does Desktop App Converter apps have access to event analytics API?

Tags: uwp, desktop-bridge, desktop-app-converter

I have been investigating the DAC tool for converting a desktop app for the Windows Store. I was wondering if the UWP custom event analytics is available to my WPF desktop app once in the store?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/log-custom-events-for-dev-center

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you cannot call this API directly from your converted WPF app. We have work booked to enable this in a future update.

As a workaround today you could add a UWP component to your converted app package and trigger that component to make the API call from there.

Thanks,
Stefan Wick - Windows Developer Platform